# How to get only KMS Customer managed keys alone from AWS Account using python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get only the count of Customer managed keys from AWS Account.
I am getting the double count of what is there in AWS Account.
It is getting AWS managed keys as well.
So i want to know how to get the count of only Customer managed keys from KMS.

Python code:

```
for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.client('kms', aws_access_key_id=access_key, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)

    resp = conn.list_keys()
    for keys in resp:
      kms_count.append(keys)
print("kms" + str(len(kms_count)))
```

Comment: HOW to get only Customer managed keys from KMS? can anyone help here please?

Comment: can anyone help me here!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `list_aliases` method to do so.
For AWS managed keys, the alias has `'alias/aws/'` as a prefix string.
You can apply your logic over the same to get only the Customer Managed keys from KMS.

I've updated your code snippet as per the requirement:

```
kms_count=[]
for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.client('kms', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)

    resp = conn.list_aliases()['Aliases']
    for keys in resp:
        if 'alias/aws/' not in keys['AliasName']:
            kms_count.append(keys)
print("kms count: " + str(len(kms_count)))
```

Hope this helps!